# Access: How to add all fields to a Query in Design View

Tags: ms-access

I know, in Access, it's possible to have the query display all fields in Design View via the Asterisk entry in the Show Table list. However, is there a way to easily add all of the fields so they appear individually, aside from double-clicking or dragging them?

Comment: Click on 1 of the columns, press Ctrl-A to select them all and drag all.

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click on the 'header' section of the table to select all fields, and then drag them onto the query builder grid:

[image]

Comment: Oh. My. God. That's freaking brilliant! That's EXACTLY what I was looking for. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that standard selection methods work for these, like either shift-clicking or control-clicking allows selection of multiple items in the list.